# js - How to call an async function within a Promise .then()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

First, I have to mention that I already look through many questions in stackoverflow, but many doesn't answer my question. Not to mention many doesn't even have an answer.

How do I achieve the following, making sure `functionB()` executes after `functionA()` finishes?

**Note: I do not want to convert my async functions to `new Promise(resolve=>{...})`** 
because I'll have to convert the `someServiceThatMakesHTTPCall()` as well, and any other async functions within the call stack, which is a big change.

```
  function functionThatCannotHaveAsyncKeyword() {
      functionA()
        .then(async function() {
            await functionB();
        })
        .then(function() {
            console.log('last');
        });
  }

  async function functionA() {
      console.log('first');
      await someServiceThatMakesHTTPCall();
  }

  async function functionB() {
      console.log('second');
      await someServiceThatMakesHTTPCall();
  }
```

Comment: NO, you haven't to convert your `someServiceThatMakesHTTPCall`, because there is no difference between async function and Promises

Comment: `async () => true // returns Promise`

Comment: I advise you to learn how promises work, because async/await is an extension of them (almost syntactical sugar!). I swear it's easier than you think :)

Comment: `functionThatCannotHaveAsyncKeyword` if that function is not meant to be **awaited** from something else, it **can** be `async`, because it will return a `Promise<void>` which will be **ignored** by the caller. Besides, `return functionB()` instead of the async-await is just enough for your case.

Comment: @CristianTraìna do you have a favorite tutorial for this?  I should also post mine after I make some progress

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Your approach using `await` in an `async` `then` callback will work, but it's unnecessarily complex if *all* you want to do is call the `async` function and have its result propagate through the chain. But if you are doing other things and want the syntax benefit of `async` functions, that's fine. I'll come back to that in a moment.

`async` functions returns promises, so you just return the result of calling your function:

```
function functionThatCannotHaveAsyncKeyword() {
    functionA()
        .then(function() {
            return functionB(someArgument);
        })
        .then(function() {
            console.log('last');
        }); // <=== Note: You need a `catch` here, or this function needs
            // to return the promise chain to its caller so its caller can
            // handle errors
}
```

If you want to pass `functionA`'s resolution value into `functionB`, you can do it even more directly:

```
functionA()
    .then(functionB)
    // ...
```

When you return a promise from a `then` callback, the promise created by the call to `then` is *resolved to* the promise you return: it will wait for that other promise to settle, then settle the same way.

Example:

```js
const wait = (duration, ...args) => new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, duration, ...args);
});

async function functionA() {
    await wait(500);
    return 42;
}

async function functionB() {
    await wait(200);
    return "answer";
}

functionB()
.then(result => {
    console.log(result); // "answer"
    return functionA();
})
.then(result => {
    console.log(result); // 42
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle error...
});
```

Coming back to your approach using an `async` `then` callback: That works too, and makes sense when you're doing more stuff:

```js
const wait = (duration, ...args) => new Promise(resolve => {
   setTimeout(resolve, duration, ...args);
});

async function functionA() {
    await wait(500);
    return 42;
}

async function functionB() {
    await wait(200);
    return "answer";
}

functionB()
.then(async (result) => {
    console.log(result); // "answer"
    const v = await functionA();
    if (v < 60) {
        console.log("Waiting 400ms...");
        await wait(400);
        console.log("Done waiting");
    }
    console.log(v);      // 42
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle error...
});
```

Comment: Before this, I tried 
        .then(async function() {
            return await functionB();
        })
which doesnt work, i'll try your solution and see if it works and get back here

Comment: @ZhuHang - `.then(async function() { return await functionB(); })` works just fine, you must have had some *other* problem in the code. But `.then(function() { return functionB(); })` does the same thing more directly.

Comment: @t-j-crowder It seems so, I realised I have another problem that makes all my previous attempts seemed to be not working. Let me get back in a moment

Comment: @t-j-crowder To return promise chain back to its caller, i have to use new Promise => resolve/reject ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder how did you even write all this in 5min.

Comment: @manishkumar - I know promises fairly well, and I took typing in High School. ;-) (*One* of the best pieces of advice my mother gave me.)

Comment: @ZhuHang - No, you only need `new Promise` when you don't already have a promise. When you already have a promise, you just return the promise. `then`, `catch`, and `finally` all create promises, so often you return the result of calling them. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Comment: @t-j-crowder So like this right? -> return functionA().then(...).then(...);

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Another question which im not sure should I open new topic. How do I start with an async function in a promise chain? Instead of "functionA().then()", I need something like: "(async function(){...}).then()"

Comment: @ZhuHang - Yes, like that. Re starting with an `async` function: Remember that an `async` function is just syntax sugar for a function returning a promise. So you'd just use `functionA().then(...).then(...)`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I mean leave those functionA & functionB away for a moment. If I want to start with an async function, how is the syntax? `(async function(){...}).then(...).then(...)`

Comment: @ZhuHang - I don't understand the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder From your `async then` callback example, u demonstrated how to use `async` inside a `then()`. My question is how to start the promise chain with an async function before any `then()`.

Comment: @ZhuHang - I showed you that in the answer; see the first code block. I recommend reading up on `async` functions and promises. An `async` function returns a promise, so if it's your starting point, you're starting with a promise.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no no. I understand both your examples. I'm asking how to start a promise chain with a "define-on-the-spot-async-function". In your example, u call `functionA()` at beginning of chain, which is a "predefined-async-function". Do u get me? haha

Comment: @ZhuHang - You could use an IIFE: `(async function() { /*...*/ })().then(/*...*/)...` The only difference between that and your example in a comment above is that I'm *calling* it (the `()` before `.then`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see! I'm missing the `()`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think the async await approach inside `then()` still doesn't work. The reason why your example work is because `.wait()` is using promise-resolve, so it will "wait" with or without the `await` keyword. But if my function is such as: `functionB() { await someAsyncA(); await someAsyncB() await someAsyncC() }` , whereby all these 3 functions do not use promise-resolve, they are not executed sequentially.

Comment: @ZhuHang - *"...so it will "wait" with or without the await keyword..."* The `setTimeout` will, but code calling `wait` will not. Remember, promises don't make code asynchronous, they *observe* things that are *already* asynchronous. Re your functions: They'll be sequential if they return promises (which they will automatically if they're `async` functions) and you're doing that in an `async` function (otherwise, `await someAsyncA()` will be a syntax error).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder u know what? Sorry, it actually works. It's some other thing, again.

Answer (score 3):

You can use promise inside the first method as

```
function functionThatCannotHaveAsyncKeyword() {
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject)=> {
          await functionA();
          await functionB();
          console.log('last');
          resolve();    
      });
  }

  async function functionA() {
      console.log('first');
      await someServiceThatMakesHTTPCall();
  }

  async function functionB() {
      console.log('second');
      await someServiceThatMakesHTTPCall();
  }
```

Comment: i think u need to call `resolve()` after the console log right?

Comment: @RahulPatil Your solution is almost workable but seemed need to be updated in the way zhuhang.jasper told in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

if `someServiceThatMakesHTTPCall` is async you can avoid all that by doing the following:

```
function functionThatCannotHaveAsyncKeyword() {
    functionA()
        .then(function() {
            return functionB()
        })
        .then(function() {
            console.log('last');
        });
  }

  function functionA() {
      console.log('first');
      return someServiceThatMakesHTTPCall();
  }

  function functionB() {
      console.log('second');
      return someServiceThatMakesHTTPCall();
  }
```