# Add await inside .then

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I have below code in which i want to call an await after getting response in `.then`.

```
const info = new getInfo(this.fetchDetails);
info
  .retrieve()
  .then((res) => {
    const details = this.getLatestInfo(res, 'John');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

In nutshell want to make `const details = this.getAgentInfo(res, 'John');` as `const details = await this.getLatestInfo(res, 'John');` but its giving error as "*await is only valid in async function*", how to make this async?

Comment: But `details` is not used anywhere or returned. Why do you need to `await` it?

Comment: How would you usually make a function async? Have you looked up "async" in a JS reference like the one on MDN?

Comment: Did you try `.then(res => this.getLatestInfo(res, 'John')).then(details => { /* your code here */ })`

Comment: @VLAZ How to return it properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [js - How to call an async function within a Promise .then()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54901478/js-how-to-call-an-async-function-within-a-promise-then)

Comment: @Lara return it where? From the promise chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing `then()` and its syntactic variant `async / await` is like speaking with two different accents. Rewriting the code to strictly use each variation, we get:

1. Older way:

   ```
    function promiseReturningFunction() {
      const info = new getInfo(this.fetchDetails);
      return info.retrieve().then((res) => {
        return this.getLatestInfo(res, 'John');
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }

    // call it
    promiseReturningFunction().then(res => {
      // res will be the result of getLatestInfo()
    }
   ```
2. Newer way:

   ```
    async function promiseReturningFunction() {
      const info = new getInfo(this.fetchDetails);
      try {
        const res = await info.retrieve();
        const info = await this.getLatestInfo(res, 'John');
        return info;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }

    // call it
    const res = await promiseReturningFunction(); // res will be the result of getLatestInfo()
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `async` keyword to make the function async as shown below.

```
const info = new getInfo(this.fetchDetails);
info
  .retrieve()
  .then(async (res) => {
    const details = await this.getLatestInfo(res, 'John');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: While this works, it doesn't really make much sense.