# Why is the reference not being saved along with the rest of the data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

I am new with MongoDB "relations" and I am trying to save data to a MongoDB database. There are two models, one model is the user and the other model is the authentication data. The data is saved correctly.

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose'

const stringRequired = {
  type: String,
  trim: true,
  required: true
}

const stringUnique = {
  ...stringRequired,
  unique: true
}

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: stringRequired,
  username: stringUnique,
  email: stringUnique,
}, { timestamps: true });

const AuthSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  salt: stringRequired,
  hash: stringRequired,
}, { timestamps: true })

export const userModel = model('User', UserSchema)
export const authModel = model('Auth', AuthSchema)
```

As you can see, one of the models is referenced by another. The email field has a reference to the user, email being the id that I want to use for authentication. But for some reason, when I save the documents, all the data is sent except the reference.

This is my controller, which as you can see, abstracts the user and the authentication to carry out the business logic and then save it in the database separately.

```
function add(body: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!body) {
        const error = new Error('No body on the request')
        reject(error)
      } else {
        const user = {
            username: body.username,
            email: body.email,
            name: body.name
        }

        const saltRouds = 10
        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(saltRouds)
        const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(body.password, salt)
        const auth = { salt, hash }

        store.add(userModel, user)
        store.add(authModel, auth)
        resolve('User created')
      }
    })
  }
```

This is the store.add function.

```
async function add (collection: any, data: any) {
  return await collection.create(data)
}
```

Note this code is writhed with Typescript.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is, but you are not waiting for the two calls to `store.add()` to finish before resolving your promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the reference key when creating the Auth instance. The "foreign key" in MongoDB is the id of a document that has type `Schema.Types.ObjectId` and can be accessed with `document._id`.

So your code should look like:

```
const auth = { salt, hash };

const user = store.add(userModel, user);
auth.email = user._id;

store.add(authModel, auth);
```

---

Be aware that your `store.add()` function is an async function and you should wait for it's result like @jfriend00 said in the comments.

You can achieve that by making `add()` also an async funtion and doing:

```
const auth = { salt, hash };

const user = await store.add(userModel, user);
auth.email = user._id;

await store.add(authModel, auth);
```

or using the Promise approach by chaining `.then()`. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54901478/js-how-to-call-an-async-function-within-a-promise-then).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's solve my problem as well. Now when I delete my user it will keep its auth reference, is there a way to deal with this? I want their authentication removed as well. What I mean is, is there a method that can do it automatically or do I have to create it?

Comment: It can be achieved through Middlewares. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14349259) is a solution to implement this "cascade" delete.

Comment: I have understanding .remove is deprecated. It's recommendable to use it?

Comment: I'm not aware of that. It is still available in the [official documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html). Maybe a `document.remove()` is deprecated, but the middleware makes use of `model.remove()`.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried with that, and the .exec method. But the middleware is not running. I place another question in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67037269/trying-to-delete-a-object-reference-in-mongodb-with-mongoose-on-nodejs/67037585?noredirect=1#comment118495780_67037585