# Trying to delete a object reference in MongoDB with mongoose on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, reference, nosql

I am trying to remove a reference created in a MongoDB database. To make it better understood, I have two models, the user and the authentication. Every time I create a user, the authentication is created as a reference, saving its value in the email field.
All that works perfectly, the problem is when I try to delete the user, the reference remains in the same place.

These are my models, user and authentication:

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose'

const stringRequired = {
  type: String,
  trim: true,
  required: true
}

const stringUnique = {
  ...stringRequired,
  unique: true
}

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: stringRequired,
  username: stringUnique,
  email: stringUnique,
}, { timestamps: true });

const userModel = model('User', UserSchema)

const AuthSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  salt: stringRequired,
  hash: stringRequired,
}, { timestamps: true })

const authModel = model('Auth', AuthSchema)

export { userModel, authModel }
```

Searching the internet I have come across a supposed solution:

```
UserSchema.pre('deleteOne', function () {
  const user = this
  user.model('AuthSchema').deleteOne({ email: user._id})
})
```

In the mongoose documentation it says that it is a kind of prehook to execute a preventive action. It made sense to me, since according to the code, the reference (auth) is removed and then the object (user). Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you actually call the `deleteOne()` for user? Do you call it on the User Model, or on an instance of it?

This seems relevant as per the documentation for the pre hook options parameter:

*[options.document] «Boolean» If name is a hook for both document and query middleware, set to true to run on document middleware. For example, set options.document to true to apply this hook to Document#deleteOne() rather than Query#deleteOne().*

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-pre

They further provide an example:

```
toySchema.pre('deleteOne', function() {
  // Runs when you call `Toy.deleteOne()`
});

toySchema.pre('deleteOne', { document: true }, function() {
  // Runs when you call `doc.deleteOne()`
});
```

Comment: Whoever calls .deleteOne is the model. I was debugging and noticed that the hook is never called.

Comment: Just to be clear when you say model: is this actually the User model - the one exported as model('User', UserSchema) - , or is this a model instance - created with new User()?

Comment: It is not an instance of the model, it is the model as well.